# How do i call a useReducer dispatch function from another file, which is not a react component? (without using Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a function component which displays a game board: "EnemyBoardComponent.tsx"

```
const enemyBoardReducer = (state:number[][], action:Action)=>{
 switch(action.type){
   case "update":
   {
      return EnemyBoard.getGrid(); 
   }
 }
}
const EnemyBoardComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [enemyBoard, enemyBoardDispatch] = useReducer(enemyBoardReducer,EnemyBoard.getGrid());
  const handleClick = (posX: number, posY: number) => {
    GameController.sendAttack(posX, posY);
  };
  return (
    <div className="gameboard">
      //code to map the gameboard
    </div>
  );
};
export { EnemyBoardComponent };
```

In the "GameController.ts" file, i'd like to dispatch an action to this component when i receive a response from the server.

```
const GameController = (() => {
  const updateEnemyBoard = (grid: number[][]) => {
    EnemyBoard.setGrid(grid);
    // need to call enemyBoardDispatch({type: "update"}) from here
  };
  return {
    sendAttack,
    receiveAttack,
    updateEnemyBoard,
  };
})();

export { GameController };
```

It's similar to this question but I'm not using redux in my project. Is it possible to do this or should i be looking into using redux?

Comment: UseReducer hook

Comment: I am using a useReducer hook already. My question was how to dispatch an action from another file.

Comment: It looks like hooks can and should only be called from React function components https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: I see, does this also apply to the dispatch? I'm not trying to call a hook outside a component. Just need to dispatch an action to update the state. Would I need to use redux as mentioned in the linked post in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: "you can't".  Hooks can only be called inside of a React function component, and the `dispatch` function returned by the `useReducer` hook is only accessible inside the scope of that function component.

You *could* hypothetically take the `dispatch` function and pass it over to that other module for it to call when needed, but that would get a bit complicated.

My main observation here is that the sample code shows a very OOP-style approach to solving this problem, and that's really the opposite of how reducers get used.  I would suggest trying to rethink the "controller" logic, and manage that inside of the reducer itself.  That's really the power of reducers - you announce "this event happened", and let the reducer take care of figuring out what the actual state update needs to be.